# Problem in loading CSS of the website in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I copied src code of one react project to another new one, and while doing so, all the code works fine in the browser but all the CSS works seems to vanish! There's no styling shown in the website.

I noticed that the config and scripts folder is not there in my new project which is in create-react-app

Comment: We gonna need way more info dude. How are you including the CSS? Are both projects using Webpack? If so, do they have the same config? Did you look into any of this?

Comment: Did you check out your Webpack configurations?

Comment: We need more details about the problem. please read a section on how to ask good questions on Stack overflow.

Comment: @AhsanAhmed, where do I check Webpack configurations?

Comment: @Jayce444, I noticed that the config and scripts folder is not there in my new project which is in create-react-app

Comment: @codelover Webpack config is usually in the root folder of the project, inside `webpack.config.js`. However, if you made an app with `create-react-app` then they abstract the config stuff away from you. In modern apps there's usually a LOT of extra config around building it, you can't just copy the `src/` folder. And there may not be an easy fix for those situations. Not knowing anything about how both these apps are built, nor anything about their configuration, I don't think we'll be able to help you much. It's not ideal, but you'd be better off copying EVERYTHING, not just `src/` files

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and what I did is copied all the `CSS` files in the public folder.

Comment: its a low quality question. best to post possible solutions as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CSS defined in **public/index.html** and you forgot to copy this file 
Maybe project was **eject** and some important changes are exist in config file to call and use CSS